# How to allow user other than Administrator to Add New User in DotnetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke

In **DotNetNuke**, **Administrator** only can **add new user**. I want to allow other user with custom role as well to Add New User. Is it possible with DotNetNuke ?

Answer (score 0):

It used to be possible, though I haven't tried this in quite a while.

Basically what you can try a couple of options.

1) You can assign PAGE permissions on the User Accounts page in DNN to users of a specific role. Then you will need to provide those users a LINK to the page, as they won't see the admin menu and won't have access to the link via the Admin menu.

2) You can actually (used to be able to) place the User account module on a page that other roles have access to, the problem is that the User Accounts and Security roles modules are "premium" meaning that you have to specifically (as a superuser) allow them for use in a portal before they can be placed on a page. You do this from the host/extensions page and click on the edit pencil next to the module, find the premium section then assign it to the specific portal. Then you will add the module(s) to a page, you'll find that more than just the User Account module gets added, so you will want to remove the extra ones by deleting them from the page.

Hopefully one of those two options will work for you.